# can not connect to mysql8 with correct password in my java project

Tags: java, mysql

I am using mysql 8.0.18 as my db, and I can log in the console with my password
but when I lanuch my springboot 2.1.3 project, and request the interface, the exception said that I can not get a jdbc connection,because "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)", the mysql password I enter is the same when I enter in the console
I had tried to set the password in springboot properties or in comandline with -Dspring.datasource.password=xxx, but both of them did not work. I am using Window10.

**Can somebody help me?**

now,i add two config in my.ini files,and i can log in the mysql db without password in window console
but my springboot project still say 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'',what can i do ?
here is the sprintboot yml pros

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    url: jdbc:MySQL://localhost:3306/maple_valley?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

Comment: What happens if you try to access the server as _127.0.0.1_ instead _localhost_

Comment: Could you show us the code ?

Comment: @FrankPentangeli what code, the exception message ?

Comment: @davidmpaz did not work

Comment: @Zero.zheng, in addition to davidmpaz, connect to db as an admin, then check the root user records, SELECT host, user, password FROM user WHERE user = 'root'; if the root@localhost record exists? how many host are there?

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK hi,there just one record , there is no `password` field,one field name `authentication_string`

Comment: would you create or update the user you want to connect, then try again? host and user should be matched.  even better have a look at mysql admin document.

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK yes,i create a new user,but that still did not work

Comment: can you please show us again the select query results and the error/exception you get now?

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK It always say 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''，now,i change my setting so that i can log in the mysql database without password on console,but my springboot project still say 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''